# Exchange 2007, Powershell to find all messages with attachments?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

Maybe my "search-fu" isn't good enough but I thought it would have been a simple process to find all messages in a mailbox that had attachments. Then I was going to figure out the attachment type and attachment size. But I haven't found anything that works for Exchange 2007.

Anybody have a solution? (Preferably without EWS)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check an exchange mailbox via powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454165/how-to-check-an-exchange-mailbox-via-powershell)

Comment: That suggested answer has no information about finding ONLY items with attachments, as specified in title. Also uses EWS, hoping for a more native solution, as specified in body of text. I hope that you are not driving away possible solution providers with a misleading duplication tag.

Comment: According to the Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 SDK documentation on MSDN, there are a variety of interfaces to Exchange Server. I'd suggest choosing which ones you'd prefer, and then focus on one of those. Why specifically don't you want to use EWS? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579101(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: As best I can tell from MSDN, using EWS is the recommended approach, for retrieving items in the Exchange datastore, by Microsoft. Furthermore, Exchange 2013, Office 365, and Exchange Online all use EWS, going forward, for management.

Comment: Local bureacracy limits what we can / can't use in business place. Getting the okay for EWS won't be quick or easy. I have seen / used most of the interfaces available to Exchange 2007, but finding by attachment is not something I can find anywhere / sort out on my own; thus I am asking for specific examples.

Comment: Would using some version of Microsoft Office Outlook automation be appropriate, through PowerShell?

Comment: And to add, I have been able to programatically retrieve everything in E2K7 with powershell (native with Exchange module loaded) for the last 6+ years including designing help desk staff interfaces so I am not untested with working with exchange interfaces. It is this specific problem that I asked for assistance.

Comment: There aren't any cmdlets in the Exchange Management Tools that will do what you are asking for, and even EWS may not get you there very easily.  Glen Scales has a sample script here: http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2013/09/exchange-attachment-statistics.html#!/2013/09/exchange-attachment-statistics.html but notes that Exchange 2007 does not return the AttachmentSize information via EWS.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying with Glen's script earlier, but it wasn't taking me where I needed to be and of course management wants a report yesterday of all mailboxes that have attachements, and a list of those attachments and their associated file types and sizes. So, I was hoping that I would find something similar to Glen's I could edit in a quicker timeframe. Thanks mjolinor.