# Take data from an email and upload it to Microsoft Sharepoint 2010

Tags: email, sharepoint, outlook

I have an email that arrives every day at 5:00 PM which reports the amount of inventory in stock everyday. Is there a way I could upload the data from this email into Microsoft Sharepoint 2010 ? I searched Google and StackOverflow but didn't find a solution to this.

Thank you in advance. A high level solution or a detail solution on how to do this would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has the ability to receive messages and documents via e-mail through functionality called Mail Enabled Libraries.

First, you have to configure incoming email, which is a bit of work. Once SharePoint is configured to receive email, you have to configure a list to receive email.

References:

- http://davecoleman146.com/2010/10/20/how-to-setup-mail-enabled-document-libraries-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1/
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287879(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT**

The manual process to upload a document would have the following steps:

1. Check email
2. If the email is there, save email to local file
3. Upload file to SharePoint

If you want to automate this process, I recommend PowerShell as its powerful yet easy to use.

- Learning PowerShell: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx
- Checking Email with PowerShell: [How to check an exchange mailbox via powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454165/how-to-check-an-exchange-mailbox-via-powershell)
- Saving an Email with PowerShell: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/335a888b-bf85-4a36-a555-71cc84608960/download-email-content-text-from-exchange-ews-with-powershell?forum=ITCG
- Uploading a file to SharePoint With PowerShell: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19529.sharepoint-2010-upload-file-in-document-library-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: I don't have the ability to set mail in my server. Is there another way ?

Comment: Aside from the normal methods of uploading documents to SharePoint? A programmatic solution would be difficult as you would have to get the email from your mail server then upload it to SharePoint, essentially automating the manual process of the traditional upload methods.

Comment: I guess I would have to do that. Would you happen to know any references to do this ?