# Write-Host in $() SubExpression always outputs at beginning of string

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to add color to characters in a string using Write-Host in a subexpression, but it only outputs to the beginning of the string.

For example:

```
"This is $(Write-Host 'failing to work' -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline)"
```

Outputs:

```
failing to workThis is
```

My goal is to make it easily reusable with something like:

```
function color {
    Write-Host $Args -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
}
"Add $(color 'to') strings"
```

---

#### EDIT

Thanks, lots of options [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688547/muliple-foreground-colors-in-powershell-in-one-command), but I don't see an explanation as to why $(Write-Host) behaves this way.

Comment: You are getting this behavior because Powershell is evaluating the sub-expression $() first before it can evaluate the string expression "This is..."

Comment: Other cmdlets work as expected here. For example: `"Today is $((Get-Date).DayOfWeek)"` . How is Write-Host different?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for Write-Host, you'll note that its output is None. That's because it doesn't have a return a value, it writes directly to the host screen. Out-Host will also have a similar effect.

Comment: I've rephrased the question because it really ought to be answered somewhere other than in a question marked closed/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802919/why-does-a-subexpression-of-write-host-output-to-beginning-of-string