# Why does a subexpression of $(Write-Host) output to beginning of string?

Tags: powershell

Using Write-Host in a $() subexpression always outputs to the beginning of a string, regardless of its position.

For example:

```
"This is $(Write-Host 'now at the beginning' -NoNewline)"
```

Outputs:

```
now at the beginningThis is
```

Other cmdlets work as expected here (e.g. `"Today is $((Get-Date).DayOfWeek)"`, `Today is Friday`).

How is Write-Host different?

Comment: `Write-Host` write string to host and not return anything.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't "output to the beginning of the string", it writes to the host twice, in 'backwards' order.

1. `"abc $()"` is a string literal that includes a sub-expression.
2. Calculating what the string is, means evaluating the `$()`
3. Evaluating the `$()` writes to the screen `now at the beginning` and returns nothing
4. Now the string literal is `"abc"`
5. Now `"abc"` is written to the screen `now at the beginningabc`

This is not doing what you suggest:

1. `"abc $(write-host 'hi')"`
2. `"hiabc"`
3. write to screen.