# Output Format-Table line color for certain results

Tags: powershell

Im running the code below and it works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path T: -Filter *.pfx | ForEach-Object { 
    Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $_.FullName -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password ****** -Force -AsPlainText) -Exportable 
} |
Format-Table -Property @{Label="Computador"; Expression={$env:computername}},
    @{Label="Nome"; Expression={$_.FriendlyName}},
    @{Label="Validade"; Expression={$_.NotAfter}},
    @{Label="Impressão digital"; Expression={$_.Thumbprint}} -AutoSize
```

I'm trying to write each line with expiring certificates with red color.
If I try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path T: -Filter *.pfx | ForEach-Object { 
    Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $_.FullName -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password ****** -Force -AsPlainText) -Exportable 
} |
Format-Table -Property @{Label="Computador"; Expression={$env:computername}},
    @{Label="Nome"; Expression={$_.FriendlyName}},
    @{Label="Validade"; Expression={$_.NotAfter}},
    @{Label="Impressão digital"; Expression={$_.Thumbprint}} -AutoSize |
Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
```

All lines become red.
If I try to pass $_ value to a If, the console says that is a Null value.

Any suggestions?

---

The solution for what I wanted to do was provided by mklement0. I will leave what I did here, if someone has the same question:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path T: -Filter *.pfx | ForEach-Object {
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $_.FullName -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password ****** -Force -AsPlainText) -Exportable
            } | Format-Table -Property @{Label="Computador"; Expression={$env:computername}}, @{Label="Nome"; Expression={$_.FriendlyName}}, @{Label="Validade"; Expression={$_.NotAfter}}, @{Label="Status"; Expression={if (($_.NotAfter).subtract([DateTime]::Now).days -lt 0){"Expirado"} elseif (($_.NotAfter).subtract([DateTime]::Now).days -lt 30){"Expirando"}}},@{Label="Impressão digital"; Expression={$_.Thumbprint}} -AutoSize | Out-String -Stream |
            ForEach-Object {
                $fgArg = if ($_ -match 'Expirado') { @{ 'BackgroundColor' = 'Red'; 'ForegroundColor' = 'Black'} } elseif ($_ -match 'Expirando') { @{ 'BackgroundColor' = 'Yellow'; 'ForegroundColor' = 'Black'} } else { @{} }
                Write-Host @fgArg $_
            }
```

Comment: Note that there is [feature request on GitHub that asks for conditional coloring of `Format-Table` output](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3886).

Comment: That would be perfect. Now we just need to wait to be implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to use **`Out-String`'s `-Stream` switch**, which **enables line-by-line processing**; by default, `Out-String` outputs a single multiline string.

Here's a simple example that colors those lines that contain the substring `expired` in red (as usual in PowerShell, matching is case-insensitive by default):

```
'A valid certificate', 'An expired certificate', 'A valid certificate' | 
   Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object {
     $fgArg = if ($_ -match 'expired') { @{ 'ForegroundColor' = 'Red' } } else { @{} }
     Write-Host @fgArg $_
   }
```

The above yields:

[image]

---

If you're looking for this functionality packaged as an advanced function, see function
`Out-HostColored` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46045860/45375) of mine.

Comment: That was exacly what I wanted to do. I was sooo close, but I didn't knew the -Stream option.

Comment: @RaphaelSouza: Yes, it's a bit surprising that `Out-String` by default returns a single string.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to accomplish something that is quite difficult for PowerShell. I have written a script that would help you accomplish your goal https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Highlight-String-and-45525e27

It isn't terribly elegant, but you would use it like this

```
gci cert: -Recurse | Format-Table -Property @{Label="Computador"; Expression={$env:computername}},@{Label="Exp"; Expression={if($_.NotAfter -le (get-date)){"Expired"}}}, @{Label="Nome"; Expression={$_.FriendlyName}}, @{Label="Validade"; Expression={$_.NotAfter}}, @{Label="Impressão digital"; Expression={$_.Thumbprint}},-AutoSize | ho '.*Expired.*'
```

Good Luck!

Shane

Comment: Thanks, but the other answer was exacly what I wanted to do.