# Display row in specific color based on condition

Tags: powershell

How to display less than 20 '% freespace' in red color.

```
PS C:>> $AllServersInfo[0].Disks | Format-Table  

DriveLetter VolumeName Capacity(GB) FreeSpace(GB) % FreeSpace  
----------- ---------- ------------ ------------- -----------  
C:                     99.66        12.85                12.9  
E:          SQL Data   200.00       44.02               22.01
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - Output Color for certain results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016763/powershell-output-color-for-certain-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that by capturing tyhe output of `Format-Table` in a string. Split that on newlines and work your way through each line like this:

```
# get the table-styled info in a string
$table = $AllServersInfo[0].Disks | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String

# do we have a string to work with?
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($table)) {
    Write-Warning 'Empty output for $AllServersInfo[0].Disks'
}
else {
    # split the string on newlines and loop through each line
    $table -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
        # do not process empty or whitespace-only strings
        if (!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))) {
            # get the last part of each line to capture the value for FreeSpace
            $temp = $_.TrimEnd().Substring($_.Length - 12).TrimStart()
            # test if this represents a number
            if ($temp -match '\d+(?:\.\d+)?$') {
                # and if so, check if it is below the threshold value of 20
                if ([double]$Matches[0] -lt 20) {
                    Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host $_
                }
            }
            else {
                Write-Host $_
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Theo..thanks for the response. It's throwing an error out at line  
$temp = $_.TrimEnd().Substring($_.Length - 12).TrimStart()  

Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s): "StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex"
At C:\...................................ps1:46 char:9
+         $temp = $_.TrimEnd().Substring($_.Length - 12).TrimStart()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Theo, i have debugged it and found that first line returned is a empty '' in $table -split '\r?\n'. $_ -eq '' -> True. Any way to rectify that?

Comment: had to put in if($_ -eq $Null -or $_ -eq '') {} at the top which resolved my issue. Correct code is:
$table -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
   if($_ -eq $Null -or $_ -eq '') {}
   else 
    {
         $temp = $_.TrimEnd().Substring($_.Length - 12).TrimStart()
         if ($temp  -match '\d+(?:\.\d+)?$') 
          {
             if ([double]$Matches[0] -lt 20) { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red }
             else { Write-Host $_ }
          }
         else { Write-Host $_ }
    }
}

Comment: @KushalSolanki Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the code to handle empty or whitespave-only strings now.