# How to output an object like '$obj | Out-Default' but in color like 'write-host'

Tags: powershell

The color for '$obj  | Out-Default' is always white.  Write-Host lets you select  -ForegroundColor * -BackgroundColor.  But it doesn't show the object nice.

Test object

```
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
                String = "A"
                Num = 6
     }
```

out-default

```
String Num
------ ---
A        6
```

write-host

```
@{String=A; Num=6}
```

Comment: Use `Write-Host` in conjunction with `Out-String`: `Write-Host $($obj |Out-String) -ForegroundColor Cyan`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell - Output Color for certain results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016763/powershell-output-color-for-certain-results)

Answer (score 4):

This is not my answer, it is Mathias R. Jessen's.

Use `Write-Host` in conjunction with `Out-String`; e.g.:

```bash
Write-Host ($obj |Out-String) -ForegroundColor Cyan
```