# Coloring array filters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, formatting, highlight, select-string

Trying to figure out how to color certain filters within an array for ease of reading on console. In other words, as the console progress forward, if "[Behaviour] OnPlayerJoined" appears, color that text green.

```
$filters = @(
################## FILTERS ##################
"[Behaviour] OnPlayerJoined",
"[Behaviour] OnPlayerLeft ",
"[API] Received Notification: <Notification"
#############################################
)
mode 300
$host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "White"
$host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "Black"
cd C:\Users\$env:UserName\AppData\LocalLow\VRChat\VRChat
$taco = Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory . | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1
Get-Content -Path $taco.name -Wait | Select-String -Pattern $filters -SimpleMatch
```

Comment: Here's a [script](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/243ea8297e7db0e1c03a67ce4b1e765d) made by Mklement0 that does just that.

Comment: Excellent! Trying to figure out how to integrate this in. New to PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

- In ***PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you get the desired behavior *automatically***: in the for-display output for each matching line, **[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) now highlights the part(s) that matched**.

  - However, you don't get to control the color for highlighting, which is based on *inverting* (swapping) the current background and foreground colors; e.g., executing `'oof', 'barn', 'baz' | Select-String 'oo', 'ar', 'az'` prints:

    - [image: screenshot PSv7]
  - You can *opt-out* of highlighting with `-NoEmphasis`.
- In ***Windows PowerShell***, you'll have to **implement your own solution** - see below.

The following is a *limited* solution that would work in your case:

```
'oof', 'barn', 'baz' |             # sample input
  Select-String 'oo', 'ar', 'az' | # search for sample patter
  ForEach-Object {                 # print the matching parts in green
    $m = $_.Matches[0]
    if ($m.Index -ge 1) { Write-Host -NoNewLine $_.Line.Substring(0, $m.Index) }
    Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green $_.Line.Substring($m.Index, $m.Length)
    Write-Host $_.Line.Substring($m.Index + $m.Length)
  }
```

Sample output:

[image: screenshot custom implementation]

Note:

- Highlighting *multiple* matches per input string, in case the `-AllMatches` switch was specified, is *not* supported by the above.
- The C# source code of PowerShell (Core) 7+'s built-in implementation, which *does* support `-AllMatches` is in method `EmphasizeLine()` in class [`MatchString.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/MatchString); permalink as of this writing is [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/0c63a549528ceb8eef68cef3a441a63401a7f291/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/MatchString.cs#L316). Note that coloring is achieved by embedding VT (ANSI) escape sequences in the output strings.
- For a general-purpose pattern-based output-coloring solution, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46045860/45375), which defines custom function `Out-HostColored`, also available as a Gist.

Comment: "you'll have to roll your own"  

Comment: @Daniel :)  OK - I've "defolksied" the answer.

Comment: Aww I enjoyed seeing that side of you!  It was a pleasant surprise